# Filter not equal is it supported in Elasticsearch SQL API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-sql

According to Elasticsearch doc it doesn't support arrays in SQL api.

I ended up using filter but it's doesn't work for my case.

include product ids **works** fine

```
"body": {
            "query" :"SELECT email FROM orders WHERE  shop='domain' GROUP BY email,total_price", 
            "filter": { 
                 "term: { 
                            "line_items.product_id": "14141414"
                        } 
            }
          }
```

but when i try to exclude some product ids by adding 'not' it **doesn't work**

```
"body": {
            "query" :"SELECT email FROM orders WHERE  shop='eclatdeparis.myshopify.com' GROUP BY email,total_price", 
            "filter": { 
                "not" : {
                   "filter" : {
                        "term": { 
                            "line_items.product_id": "1418646978625"
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

is it any trick for exclude ?????
Thanks in advance